# Unable to locate package msodbcsql

Tags: software-installation, sql

I'm trying to install ms sql driver on Ubuntu 16.04. Here are steps I run :

```
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   983  100   983    0     0    164      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   231
OK

$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    79  100    79    0     0    130      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   131

$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 306 kB in 3s (86.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql=13.1.4.0-1
The result : 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql
```

Here is the contain of file mssql-release.list :

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main
```

What step did I miss?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you get these instructions?

Comment: I get from this site : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: But that page mentions installing `msodbcsql17`, not `msodbcsql`.

Comment: Scroll down the page, the instruction can be found in the section Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server >> Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I followed the same instructions, and there is a package `msodbcsql` in that repo. In fact there are 11 versions, the most recent being 13.1.9.2. So you should be able to `apt install` it. You can verify that by doing `apt policy msodbcsql`. Did you do `sudo apt update`?

Comment: As your suggested, I run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql=13.1.9.2` but still get same error.

Comment: Just do `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt install msodbcsql`. It will install the latest version.

Comment: Still get this error `E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql`

Comment: What do you get with `apt policy msodbcsql`?

Comment: I got `N: Unable to locate package msodbcsql`

Comment: Sorry my fault. The ubuntu server was 32 bit. No error anymore when I upgrade to 64 bit. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I had been scratching my head about why it would work on my system but not on yours.